# Why cant we use reference in algorithms and data structure?

Tags: c++

> As a general rule, use references in function parameters and return
>   types to define attractive interfaces. Use pointers to implement
>   algorithms and data structures.

I read this line in an article.I had the doubt of why reference cannot be used in algorithms and datastructures?

Please help me undestand why is it.

Comment: shouldn't this be tagged C++ instead of C?

Comment: Please cite that quote so others can read the surrounding context.

Comment: Its from introduction to pointers article pdf by dan saks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because a reference can't be made to refer to any other object after it's been initialised to refer to a particular one.

As proof, §8.5.3.2 of the Standard says

> A reference cannot be changed to refer to another object after
>   initialization. Note that initialization of a reference is treated
>   very differently from assignment to it. Argument passing (5.2.2) and
>   function value return (6.6.3) are initializations.

Data structures and algorithms (though to a lesser extent) usually involve adding, removing, and reordering objects within themselves. With references you cannot do this, so you use pointers to do it inexpensively.

Comment: @stign that's not the same. You just changed the value of `a` in that line, you didn't make `c` refer to `b`. Further assignments to `c` will only further change `a`s value, not `b`s value.

Comment: @stijn: You're wrong, your code snippet does not modify the reference, but the object that is referenced. After it, `a` will have the same value as `b` (provided they are initialized), but `&c` will have the same value as `&a`, not the same value as `&b`.

Comment: @stijn Updated with a quote from the standard if you have doubts. The quote actually addresses the specific example you showed. I'd appreciate it if you removed your downvote.

Comment: thanks for the update; I completely misunderstood what you were saying, my mistake.